# Does anyone know about sample structure table for save parameter and procedure name (Oracle)?

Tags: database, oracle

Please help me.
I want to make a table where it can save list of store_procedures and parameters. 
After that I want make a trigger to excute all the procedures with some interval time.
What I want to ask is column suggestion/advices for this table?
Thank you. :D

Below is my opinion:

```html
<table border='1'>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>PROCEDURE</th>
        <th>PARAMETERS</th>
        <th>PROCESS</th>
        <th>DATE_TIME_EXECUTED</th> 
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>procd_1</td>
        <td>A-1,B-2</td>
        <td>Failed</td>
        <td>01-08-2019 09:01:01</td> 
     </tr>   
     <tr>
        <td>procd_2</td>
        <td>A-3,B-5,C-7</td>
        <td>Waiting</td>
        <td>01-08-2019 09:01:02</td> 
     </tr>  
     <tr>
        <td>procd_3</td>
        <td>A-3,C-7  </td>
        <td>New</td>
        <td>NULL</td> 
     </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hint: triggers don't work like that. A trigger is fired when a database event occurs, such as an INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE statement is executed. They can't be fired on a time interval. You might want to look at the DBMS_JOBS package. Or on *nix investigate `cron`.

Comment: Thank you. Mr. Bob Jarvis. I'm new about this idea. I will look at.

Comment: Though, package name is `DBMS_JOB`. Also, depending on database version you use, have a look at `DBMS_SCHEDULER` which provides additional functionalities (but is more complex).

Comment: Also to store the parameters as comma separated values is not good idea as your table will break 1NF rule. This also might create problem in future if you need to add/remove any parameter. Store them on separate rows.

Comment: For future reference, you should use [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for formatting. Using backticks to encapsulate data (and code) is so much simpler than all those `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Mr/ Mrs Littlefoot, Ankit Bajpai, APC for sharing knowledge. It's very helpfull. I will find the more about that. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two tables to store all the information.
One for Procedure information and one for Parameters information.

Something like following will help you out.

**DDL of tables**

```
create table procedures_tbl 
(
procedures_tbl_uid number primary key,
procedure_name varchar2(128),
last_execution_start_time date,
last_execution_end_time date,
last_execution_status varchar2(32)
);

create table parameters_tbl
(
parameters_tbl_uid number primary key,
procedures_tbl_fk number references procedures_tbl (procedures_tbl_uid),
parameter_name varchar2(128),
parameter_data_type varchar2(20),
parameter_value varchar2(4000),
parameter_input_type varchar2(6) CHECK (parameter_input_type IN ('IN','OUT','IN OUT'))
);
```

**Inserting data to tables**

```
INSERT INTO procedures_tbl 
VALUES
(
1,
'procd_1',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL
);


INSERT INTO parameters_tbl
VALUES
(
1001,
1,
'A',
'NUMBER',
'1',
'IN'
);


INSERT INTO parameters_tbl
VALUES
(
1002,
1,
'B',
'NUMBER',
'2',
'IN'
);
```

**Fetching the data**

```
SELECT PROC.procedure_name, 
PAR.parameter_name,
PAR.parameter_data_type,
PAR.parameter_value,
PAR.parameter_input_type,
PROC.last_execution_start_time,
PROC.last_execution_end_time,
PROC.last_execution_status
FROM procedures_tbl PROC JOIN parameters_tbl PAR
ON PROC.procedures_tbl_uid = PAR.procedures_tbl_FK
WHERE PROC.procedure_name = 'procd_1';
```

You can see the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c301cc5f49a183fe8e002b6bd65fe6c)

Cheers!!

Comment: Oh. yes. Thank you so much Mr. Tejash for the answers. The table now look more effecient. Very helpful.